# Grouped bar chart in Altair with labels

Tags: python, bar-chart, altair

I'm trying to create a grouped bar chart in Altair with labels. Based on this post from @jakevdp [grouped bar with labels](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1329). I was able to create the following chart:

[image: altair grouped bars with labels]

This is my code:

```
`def missing_vals1(data, debug= False):
    chart = alt.Chart(data).mark_bar(size=15).encode(
        x= alt.X(field= 'claim', 
                 type='nominal', 
                 axis= alt.Axis(labels=False, 
                               title= None,
                               ticks=False),
        ),
        y= alt.Y('Total:Q', 
                 axis=alt.Axis(
                     grid=False)
                ), 
        color = alt.Color('claim',
                        # header = alt.Header()
                         ),
        #column = alt.Column('claim')
        
    )
    
            
    text = chart.mark_text(
        color = 'black',
        dy= -5
    ).encode(
        text = alt.Text(
            'Total:Q',
            format = ',.0f')
    )
    
    return alt.layer(chart, text, data=data
                    ).facet(column = '#_missing'
        ).configure_view(
        continuousHeight=200,
        continuousWidth= 0.5
    )
```

`
However, I'd like to move the '#_missing' title as well as the numbers of each of the columns [0...14] to the bottom of the x axis, but it's not possible using the color encoding.

I also tried using the column encoding, but I wouldn't be able to use the labels (as explained in the link above).

Finally, I'd like to change the color of the text to all black and also reduce the spacing between columns.

Any tips are welcomed!

Edit: This is what the dataframe that I'm working with looks like
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to publish sample data? I would like to help you with your assignment.

Comment: @r-beginners I edited my question and added the table that I'm working with. This is just a groupby of the missing values in the Kaggle Tabular Playground Series for September, you can find the full dataset here [](https://www.kaggle.com/c/tabular-playground-series-sep-2021)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1:** I want to move the title and x-axis label down in the graph.
This can be set in Facet in the header details.

**Issue 2:** I want to make the column spacing narrower.
This can be done by setting the spacing in the Facet configuration.

**Issue 3:** I want to change the color of the text to all black.
It seems that the color of the bar chart and the text cannot be changed to the same color. At the time of my research, there may be a way to do this. My experiment was to try and change the range of colors on [this page](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/920) to black, but both the bars and the text are black.

```
alt.layer(chart, text, data=data).facet(
    column=alt.Column(
        '#_missing:Q',
        header=alt.Header(titleOrient='bottom', labelOrient='bottom'))
    ).configure_view(
    continuousHeight=200,
    continuousWidth= 0.5
).configure_facet(
    spacing=0.5
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @r-beginners for the help! I got this to work mostly. For my Issue #3 what I really meant to say was that I wanted to shrink the space between the ticks. I'll come back and post a revised version of the code to try and improve the label positioning so that they don't overlap.